# Round percentage value to nearest number

Tags: java

I wanted to convert a number which is in string format to a percentage value with one decimal point. Below is my sample input and expected output.

Expected results:

"0.0195" => "2.0%"

"0.0401" => "4.0%"

I know this may be a simple question but I am not able to find the exact solution for this using java APIs, I tried all the rounding modes present under RoundingMode enum, but no rounding mode gives my expected result. Could you please help, I may be missing something.

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class RoundingModeExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(formatPercentage("0.0195") + "(expected 2.0%)");
        System.out.println(formatPercentage("0.0401") + "(expected 4.0%)");
    }

    private static String formatPercentage(String number) {
        String formattedValue = "";
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
        numberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        try {
            formattedValue = numberFormat.format(Double.valueOf(number));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            formattedValue = number;
        }
        return formattedValue;
    }


}
```

*Output of the above program:*

*1.9%(expected 2.0%)*

*4.0%(expected 4.0%)*

Comment: Proposal: parse the `String` into a `double` ([`Double.parseDouble(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))), multiply this `double` by `100.0`, round it to nearest even ([`Math.round(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#round(double))), print it out.

Comment: [double values are not exact.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)  The compiler and runtime cannot represent 0.0195 exactly in IEEE format.  Instead, it uses 0.0194999999999999999722444243843710864894092082977294921875.

Comment: @Turing85 That won't give you the 1dp.  Multiplying by 1000, rounding, then dividing by 10 should work but it feels like a kludge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with 0.0195 is that there is no `double` precision number that is exactly mathematically equal to it. When you write 0.0195 in program source code or parse the string "0.0195" into double, the number you get is actually a little bit less. That's why the formatter rounds it to 1.9%.

You can get around this by not using the `double` data type at all:

```
formattedValue = numberFormat.format(new BigDecimal(number));
```

Comment: Thank you @Joni, this worked for me, learnt something new.